# QT creator doesn't build on iPhone Simulator Mac os X - Error 65

Tags: ios, qt, build, qt-creator

I need an help i've installed qt creator and i need to run on iOs Simulator from Qt Creator.
So if i run the build on xcode on simulator, the project works, but...if i try to start iOS simulator from QtCreator i receive error 65.
I need to start from qt creator. 
Any help ??

```
xcodebuild build  -project APO.xcodeproj -scheme APO   -configuration Debug  -destination "id=5A57549E-4CF4-4E12-87C1-1D9ABA8A30C5",        "availabilityError" : "" -destination-timeout 1 
xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'availabilityError'.
make: *** [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 65
14:18:45: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project APO (kit: Qt 5.9.2 for iOS2 Simulator)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: Given that major Mac OS, iOS and XCode were released during the past weeks, you should try again with Qt 5.11 instead of 5.9. Also, does the deployment work? I.e. can you debug your app from QtCreator if the iOS emulator is already running?

Comment: Yes i've tried with the simulator running but nothing, doesn't work. So Now i will try to update 5.9 to last 5.11 and i let you know. thanks for now

Comment: @markus-nm you're right. With Qt 5.11.2 now work correctly on simulator. Then i've some problem with library that support only 5.9 but i work it they and i will fix it. Thanks.